# How can I run agglomerative clustering in Python with pre-calculated distances?

Tags: python, hierarchical-clustering

I have some distances that look like this (but with far more elements)

```
data = [
    {'id1': 1, 'id2': 2, 'dist': 3},
    {'id1': 1, 'id2': 3, 'dist': 2},
    {'id1': 2, 'id2': 3, 'dist': 4}
]
```

I would like to cluster these into a tree, using an agglomerative clustering algorithm, similar to R's `hclust()` method. I would like to use complete linkage for my specific case, but if other methods are available, those would be good to know.

So far, all of the `sklearn` solutions I see appear to require the raw data used to compute metrics.

In case it's relevant, the objects that are being clustered are members of a class with complicated similarity/distance logic, so I am pre-computing the distances. I do have a static method `objectclass.calculate_distance(x,y)` that I use for this.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Maybe look at [Scipy Hierarchical Clustering](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.hierarchy.html)